# UIActivityViewController UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

- List item

Using Swift for an app that runs in iOS 8, I need to write a completion handler for the `UIActivityViewController` to capture the results of which "share" method a user selected.

This is a snippet of the code I have so far. My question is how to I set the `avc.completionWithItemsHandler`? I'm sure it's simple, but I don't see it.

```
var activityItems = NSMutableArray()
activityItems.addObject("Email or text for 'share' goes here")

var avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
avc.setValue("Subject for Email", forKey: "Subject")

avc.completionWithItemsHandler = //Here is where I dont know what to do.

self.navigationController?.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 41):

The completionWithItemsHandler typealias:

```
typealias UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler = (String?, Bool, [AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> Void
```

Note: the previous code block is not to be used in your project, it just shows the type of closure needed ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/c:@T@UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)).

So those are the parameters that are passed into the completion handler for you to do with as you will, so the completion handler would look like this:

```
avc.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in 

}
```

Comment: It is exactly the same code as yours but in swift. And the first block is the type alias for the completion handler some people know the parameters of the closure, not something you actually put into your project.

Comment: Okay, okay, enough :) Consider me chastised. My bad. I didn't see the "Swift" part. (i really didn't). I am gonna leave my answer but edit it to say that I mis-understood question. Also I cannot edit my vote cos answer was "16 hours ago and i cannot edit vote unless answer is edited" (for some reason)

Comment: I edited my post to prevent people from thinking you put the type alias code into their project

Comment: +1 This was a useful answer when I got the compiler warning `'completionHandler' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use completionWithItemsHandler instead.` since it shows the template of the Swift code I needed to add instead.

Answer (score 13):

**NOTE: Because I didn't read the "SWIFT" part of the question, I answered the question in Obj-C. My bad, To the OP: I apologize**

<strike>Here is a more complete answer that actually can be compiled</strike>. I used: `dispatch_async` in order to do an alert so you can see what "activityType" ended up being.

```
avc.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertViewQuick(@"Activity Status", activityType, @"OK");
    });
    if (completed)
    {
        NSLog(@"The Activity: %@ was completed", activityType);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"The Activity: %@ was NOT completed", activityType);
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean "that actually can be compiled"? This question is about Swift and you wrote an answer in Objective-C.

Comment: Okay, okay, enough :) Consider me chastised. My bad. I didn't see the "Swift" part. (i really didn't). I am gonna leave my answer but edit it to say that I mis-understood question. Also I cannot edit my vote cos answer was "16 hours ago and i cannot edit vote unless answer is edited" (for some reason)

Answer (score 3):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212987/1442935) says, for Swift 3 and 4 and iOS 10 and 11 use it like this:

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in

}

present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was answered quite a while ago, but has a mix of missing and non-swift info so here's my version in the hope that it will help someone needing a more complete example of the completion handler:

```
    avc.completionWithItemsHandler = {[weak self](activityTypeChosen, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        // ReturnedItems is an array of modified NSExtensionItem, or nil of nothing modified
        // if (activityType == nil) User dismissed the view controller without making a selection.

        // Dismiss the view controller we presented
        // (assume a reference to it was stored in self.activityVC)
        self?.activityVC?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
            if activityTypeChosen == nil {
                NSLog("User canceled without choosing anything")
            }
            else if completed {
                NSLog(")User chose an activity and iOS sent it to that other app/service/whatever OK")
            }
            else {
                NSLog("There was an error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Note the line where it dismisses the view controller. The docs for UIActivityViewController say very explicitly that your app is responsible for both presenting the VC *and* dismissing it.